# Underlined TextView is not anti-aliased

Tags: android, textview, antialiasing

When trying to make text underlined:

```
setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

`TextView` becomes non anti-aliased. If I enable anti-aliasing:

```
getPaint().setAntiAlias(true)
```

Then it becomes anti-aliased.

Is there some connection between anti-aliasing and `Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no connection betwenn anti-aliasing and `Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG`** .

But the difference is that `setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG)` will remove default existing flags & set the current flag as `Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG` only. Try the below code to keep existing flags & add new flag

```
yourTextView.setPaintFlags(yourTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: Uhh, true, so obvious. Just checked source code of `TextView` and it replaces all flags. Thanks.